# Where should I put LaTeX macro package files?

Tags: macros, packages

I'm preparing to submit an article to one of Springer's journals.
It requires to use Springer's LaTeX macro package.
(http://www.springer.com/statistics/journal/10985 --> Instruction for authors --> Text)
I downloaded the package and unzipped it. It includes readme.txt, Users Guide, template.tex and some .bst, .clo, .cls files.
Where should I put these files to use this package?

I'm using TeX Live 2013, so browsed c:/texlive/2013 and all its subfolders, but have no idea where I should put the files. This is for Windows of my home computer but I also use Mac at school, so I need answers for both Windows and Mac.

Comment: In the same directory will work. This question has been asked before, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files that are not  part of the distribution should go to the `texmf-local` root, organised according to TDS. More precisely, in the present case, you should create in texmf-local the following directories:

1) `texmf-local\doc\latex\statisticsjournal\` (or `springerjournals`, depending on whether the the files are specific to *this* journal or not), in which you put everything pertaining to documentation, including template.tex, I think.

2)`texmf-local\tex\latex\statisticsjournal\` for .clo, .cls files.

3) `texmf-local\bibtex\bst\statisticsjournal\` for .bst files.

Then run `texhash`. Your files are ready to be used.

Comment: It works for Windows. But how about Mac? I can't find the counterpart of 'texmf-local' folder

Comment: I browsed Library > TeX > Root, then there are 'texmf', 'texmf-config', 'texmf-dist', and 'texmf-var'. Should I choose one of them, or create a new folder named 'texmf-local'?

Comment: You should have your Mac distribution in `/usr/local/texlive/2014` and texmf-local should be in ` /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. These are created at installation. Things in `~\Library` are personal to a particular user, as far as I know. A problem with Macs is that a number of folders are hidden.